# Function declarations and an unresolved external

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, linker, c-preprocessor, porting

I am looking after a huge old **C** program and converting it to C++ (which I'm new to).

There are a great many complicated preprocessor hacks going on connected to the fact that the program must run on many different platforms in many different configurations.

In one file (call it `file1.c`) I am **calling** `functionA()`.
And in another file (call it `file2.c`) I have a **definition** of `functionA()`.

Unfortunately the exact type of the function is specified by a collection of macros created in a bewildering number of ways.

Now the linker is complaining that:

> functionA is an unresolved external symbol.

I suspect that the problem is that the prototype as seen in file1.c is slightly different from the true definition of the function as seen in file2.c.

There is a lot of scope for subtle differences due to mismatches between `_cdecl` and `fastcall`, and between with and without `__forceinline`.

Is there some way to show **exactly** what the compiler thinks is the type of `functionA()` as seen by `file1.c` as opposed to `file2.c`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a flag to the compiler (/P, I think) that causes it to output the complete preprocessed output that is passed to the compiler - you can then open this (huge) file, and search through it and the information you need will be in there, somewhere.

Comment: +1. Thanks... that has helped somewhat although it has now revealed a deeper mystery which I have put in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Must you actually convert all the existing C code to C++? This is likely to be a lot of work, especially given what you've described so far.

Instead, you can write new code in C++ and call into the C code using `extern "C"`. For example, in a C++ source file you can:

```
extern "C" {
#include "old_c_header.h"
}
```

This changes the linkage so the C++ compiler generates external references to the C code without name mangling, allowing the linker to match everything up.

Comment: Unfortunately I must convert it to C++ for many reasons, but thanks for the tip anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should have the expected and the actual signature in the output.

Otherwise you can instruct the compiler to output the results of the preprocessing into a seperate file, `cl.exe /p` for MSVC and for gcc `gcc -E`.

Comment: The linker reports the precise declaration of the function it is failing to find, which presumably is the one corresponding to file1.c, but I have no clue about the one corresponding to file2.c.

Comment: Too bad, i hope preprocessor output and grep/search for the function name helps.